# How to update order item product options after order placed?

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, edit-order

I am trying to change my order item custom options after order placed but it overwrite exitsting data and set only value that i did set previously.
https://www.screencast.com/t/Y99dQ1D4
My code.

```
foreach ($orderIds as $key => $value) {
       $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($value);
       $orderItem = $orderModel->getAllItems();
       foreach ($orderItem as $item) {
        if($item->getId()==17447){
           $option = $item->getProductOptions();
          $info = $intoByRequest['info_buyRequest']['additional_options']['item_shippinggroup'];
          $info = 'group1';
          $item->setProductOptions(serialize($info))
       }
    }
```

can anyone please guide me how i would change one array element and save the item.

Comment: Did you check with `save` in your code like `$item->setProductOptions(serialize($info))->save();`

Comment: yes dear i did but it save only set value :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
foreach ($orderIds as $key => $value) {
   $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($value);
   $orderItem = $orderModel->getAllItems();
   foreach ($orderItem as $item) {
        if($item->getId()==17447){
          $option = $item->getProductOptions();
          $option['info_buyRequest']['additional_options']['item_shippinggroup'] = 'group1';
          $item->setProductOptions($option)->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It overwrite all other option and save like this `s:106:"a:1:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:1:{s:18:"additional_options";a:1:{s:18:"item_shippinggroup";s:6:"group1";}}}";`

Comment: @MageLerner, Updated code, there was no need of unserializing the data.

Comment: it works but it convert all serialize string to non converted string
http://www.unserialize.com/s/204479a4-13d1-ba28-ebc1-0000152774b4

It should look like this
http://www.unserialize.com/s/6da87b87-d151-da09-dad3-000079f1dd24

Comment: Please make edit this line `$item->setProductOptions(serialize($option))->save();` to `$item->setProductOptions($option)->save();`

Comment: @JaiminSutariya Works for me!